# Convert PID to HWND

Tags: c++, winapi, process

Basically, I want to convert a process ID to a HWND. I am using this code:

```
   DWORD   dwWindowId;
   CHAR       pszClassName[200];
   HWND     hWnd;

   hWnd = GetTopWindow (NULL);

   while ( hWnd != NULL )
   {
      if ( GetClassName (hWnd, pszClassName, 200) > 0)
         if ( lstrcmpiA (lpcszWindowClass, pszClassName) == 0)
            if ( GetWindowThreadProcessId (hWnd, &dwWindowId) )
               if ( dwWindowId == dwProcessId )
                  return hWnd;

      hWnd = GetNextWindow ( hWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT );
   }
   return NULL;
```

This worked fine until I tried with a process was created by `CreateProcess`. What should I do in this case? I have the process info, such as its ID and thread ID from `CreateProcess`, but I still do not know how to get its hwnd. I did read this:

> After you call `CreateProcess()`, examine the `PROCESS_INFORMATION`
>   struct pointed to by lpProcessInformation argument.
>   `PROCESS_INFORMATION` contains a handle to the Process you just
>   started and a Thread ID. With this information call the
>   `GetGUIThreadInfo()`function and then examine the `GUITHREADINFO`
>   struct pointed to by lpgui. `GUITHREADINFO` has several HWNDs. Start
>   with hwndActive, and call `GetParent()` or `GetAncestor()` untill the
>   Main window is found.
>
> By bug_crusher

I have tried `EnumChildWindows()` and `EnumWindows()`, and they did not work.

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD PID =0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&PID);
    if(PID == 1)
    {
        //,,,,,,,,
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

But I don’t get it, can anyone explain that?

Comment: A process can have none, one, or more than one windows, there's no such thing as a "process's hwnd". `EnumWindows` and call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` for each one.

Comment: It does not work, even with EnumWindows()

Comment: What doesn't work? You need to be more specific about what you have tried, what results you expected and what results you observed.

Comment: if(PID == 1) i can get any hwnd except the one which was created by createprocess, I have no idea why///

Comment: CreateProcess doesn't create windows, it creates processes.

Comment: Are you sure the process ID is 1? I've never seen a PID less than 3 digits and they are always an even number.

Comment: it's  not 1 it's ???? if I do this manually, run app text.exe, i find its  PId and GetWindowThreadProcessId shows that, but if I do this createprocess.... test.exe, GetWindowThreadProcessId does not show that PID except taskmanger

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit confused by what you're actually trying to do, but this function will build a vector of all the top-level windows belonging to the specified process.

```
void GetWindowsOfProcess(DWORD dwId, std::vector<HWND>& vecWindows)
{
    struct WindowsOfProcess
    {
        std::vector<HWND>*  pvecWindows;
        DWORD               dwProcId;

        static BOOL CALLBACK EnumProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
        {
            DWORD dwProcId;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &dwProcId);
            if (dwProcId == reinterpret_cast<WindowsOfProcess*>(lParam)->dwProcId)
                reinterpret_cast<WindowsOfProcess*>(lParam)->pvecWindows->push_back(hWnd);
            return TRUE;
        }

        WindowsOfProcess(DWORD dwId, std::vector<HWND>* pvec)
            :   dwProcId(dwId)
            ,   pvecWindows(pvec)
        {
            EnumWindows(EnumProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(this));
        }
    };
    WindowsOfProcess wop(dwId, &vecWindows);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but i think I found a way, except if i have 2 apps have the same name test.exe and i used finiwindow, how I can find the second text.exe? is that possible?